# Can't login into Stack Overflow Portugues

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, google-chrome, portuguese-stackoverflow

I can't login into the [Stack Overflow Portugues site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/login#log-in).

I choose *Stack Exchange Login* and after that I get an ongoing *...* but nothing happens.

[image: Login]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I missed a setting during the transition.  It should be fixed now.